Why can we see color during d-d transition of electron?
As we know that when a ligand approaches the transition metals, the d-orbital loses its degeneracy and in this case electron can jump from lower orbitals to higher orbitals adsorbing the visible light. Till this I am very clear.
My question is if the energy gap is constant, when the electron returns into the lower orbitals it will emit the same wavelength of light it adsorbed while going up. Thus there is no net change in intensity of a particular wavelength light. Thus there would not be any complementary color to be shown.
Thank you in advance.

There are multiple levels [actually, an infinite number, merging into a continuum] to which an electron can be raised in an atom. For example, see the Lyman series of levels in just a simple hydrogen atom.
If an atom in a fluorescent substance is exposed to ultraviolet radiation (UV), the electron does not simply drop back to the ground state, but to a metastable state. In that process, it may immediately radiate the extra energy as infrared, or it may be lost to heating the sample. Then, when the electron drops from the metastable state to ground state, it radiates a longer wavelength that that incident UV.
An example would be copper-activated calcium sulfide ($\ce{CaS:Cu}$). When irradiated with UV-A, perhaps 365 nm, about 3.4 electron-volts (eV) in each photon, it raises an electron by 3.4 volts. The electron fairly rapidly drops to a level of ~2.8 volts, dissipating ~0.7 eV as heat, or perhaps a 1,800 nm IR photon (Likely signifucant emission is seen, as a 1-micron calcium sulfide film shows about 80% transmission in near infrared wavelengths).
Some time later (from seconds to hours, for that phosphor), the electron "falls" by ~2.8 V to ground, emitting a ~2.8 eV, blue, photon.
No energy was destroyed, just otherwise lost.

See my edit on the IR signal, with reference. Feel free to roll back if this is not appropriate.

Thanks for the response. But what I learned that the d-orbital splits into two parts. And the electron takes visible light to jump from the higher state. If there is no in-between energy state then how can the electron radiate the energy in different wavelength. Correct me if I am wrong
